# Load clicked span URL from span's id in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Kindly take a look at following JS fiddle in which I am trying to load the `Video URL` in an Iframe of a `Twitter Bootstrap's` modal along with the title from `title attr` in the modal's title bar. Kindly let me know how can I make it work?

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1745/

```
<span id="http://player.vimeo.com/video/78360422" title="Introduction to this video" class="btn btn-warning" ><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/78360422" target="ifr">1) VIDEO TO LOAD IN IFRAME # 1</a> </span><br><BR>
<span id="http://player.vimeo.com/video/53671222" title="About It" class="btn btn-warning" > 2) VIDEO TO LOAD IN IFRAME # 2 </span>

<!-- Button trigger modal --><br><BR>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Span Title Attr Text Here</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
                                                                 <iframe name="ifr" src='' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> 

      </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "span.btn", function () {
     var title = $(this).prop('title'),
         id = $(this).prop('id'); 
     $(".modal-title").text(title);
     $(".modal-body").html($("<iframe src=" + id + "></iframe>"));
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1766/

Comment: can't we load the URL in an iframe on runtime?

Comment: I have sort of list of multiple videos and their iframe URL will be in the id of span so my idea is to load the video in iframe when user clicks on the respective span in a Twitter bootstrap modal. `<iframe name="ifr" src='' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> `

Comment: by `iframe URL` I meant `iframe src URL` and id of span looks like `<span id="http://player.vimeo.com/video/78360422" title="abcd"`

Comment: yup id will go to iframe's source and {title will go to modal's title (which you alreay did)}

Answer (score 0):

1. clean up the html code maybe? It's hard to read :(
2. your second a tag target should set to '#ifr' as the way the other two link(button) work
3. set your iframe src to be your video link, something like:
   , don't put that in your span id

Comment: clean up your answer maybe? It's hard to read :( - Joking aside, you might want to re-format this answer. As it stands, it's difficult to find the solution OP is looking for.

Comment: I have a list of multiple videos and their iframe URL will be in the id of span so my idea is to load the video in iframe when user clicks on the respective div in a `Twitter bootstrap` modal

Comment: In this case, I put a working demo here, hope this would help. http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1759/

Answer (score 0):

you can open an external link in bootstrap modal with this:

```
<a data-target="#externalModal" href="externalmodal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">External url</a>
```